# How do I find and remove a setting value in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, working-directory

I am using Visual Studio Code and the terminal extension keeps trying to start using an invalid folder. I have tried setting "terminal.integrated.cwd" for both User and workspace but the problem still exists. Where can I find this setting to change it?

Note: I am editing powershell in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio Code's [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell) provides a *custom* shell that runs in the integrated terminal, the so-called PowerShell Integrated Console (PIC), which has *separate settings*.

To control the *startup working directory* of the PIC, use the `powershell.cwd` setting.
Interactively, via the Settings dialog (<kbd>Ctrl+,</kbd>), you can locate it quickly by searching for `powershell cwd`:

[image: Settings screenshot with PowerShell CWD setting]

Note the important constraint: only a full, literal path may be specified.

---

To see *all* settings relevant to the PowerShell extension, either search for `powershell` only, or - without searching - navigate to `Extensions > PowerShell` in the tree view on the left.

Comment: Thank you so much! It has been driving me up the wall, and I could not find a solution.